# How can I generate separate output files for the build output of each target in CMake?

Tags: cmake

When working with big CMake projects with many targets, CMake will intelligently build the targets in parallel. However, the build logs for all targets will just intermix in stdout getting printed to the screen. This can make understanding failures difficult.

Is there a way to generate a build log file for each target in the project?

i.e. `build_target_name_0.log`, `build_target_name_1.log`.

Comment: "CMake will intelligently build the targets in parallel" - It is not CMake who builds the target, it is a **build tool** who does that. So, if you want a separate output from a distinct targets, you need to consult your build tool (Make, Ninja, etc.).

Comment: Just an interesting note for people who land here. If you are using ExternalProject_Add, it does have LOG_BUILD option, which can give you a unique log file per external project. This is actually good enough for me. It is not target resolution, but very good feature nonetheless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CMake just generates the buildsystem based on your CMake project configuration. The order of compiling source files is determined by the buildsystem based on the buildsystem configuration files generated by CMake. I'm not aware of CMake having a configuration point that it uses to configure buildsystems to do what you are looking for. When you run the build, you can pass buildsystem-specific arguments to the build tool command. Consult your build tool's documentation.

One "CMake-supported" workaround would be to just build target-by-target, from the order of targets "lowest" in the dependency graph/tree (most depended upon), to those highest (not depended upon, but depends on other targets). Any decent buildsystem will know when a target doesn't need to be rebuilt, so this way, you can get output for just the target you build. See the [`--target`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-build-t) argument of `cmake --build`. Then just use your shell's mechanism for piping output to a file.